# How do I filter a view with a field on a group the current user is in?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

The site I'm working on will have many OG groups, each with a list of topics relevant to their members. I would like to show content to the logged in user that is about their group's relevant topics.

I started by creating a vocabulary (Topic) and two content types (Group and Post). Group and Post both have a term reference field that lists Topic terms (groups have topics that are relevant to the group, and posts have topics about which they're written).

How can I create a view that shows only posts with at least one Topic term in common with the logged in user's group's Topic list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may not be possible with the current stable release of OG (7.x-1.3). I think it would require at least the patch from [issue #1341990](http://drupal.org/node/1341990) along with the patch from [this comment on issue #1151648](http://drupal.org/node/1151648#comment-5243860), but I'm completely new to Drupal so it's not unlikely that I'm missing something.